# Upgrading to WP 5+ with block content - Export & Import Page Content

Tags: content, import, export

I'm upgrading a pre-Wordpress 5.0 site to the latest WP version using blocks.  I created a staging site and went through all the pages/posts and converted the content into blocks.  Now I need to export **ONLY** the **page/post content** (**+ custom fields**) and import it into production without effecting anything else.

I've tried the default WP import/export tool but this does not appear to work on existing pages that are already on production.

I found this topic often when I Googled it but nothing that offers a solution for me.

What are my options?

Comment: blocks are saved as HTML the same way as pre-5.0, your existing content won't be transformed unless you open every single post in the block editor, click convert to blocks, then re-save it. Otherwise I don't understand the problem. I think you're asking how to import pages into a site that already has those pages, and overwrite their content?

Comment: Essentially, yes that is what I'm asking.  I just added the bit about upgrading to 5.0+ to add some context.